# Error with DomPdf render html in php

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I try to render view HTML, with div, tables, thead, tboody, tfoot, h2, h3 and ccs.

The result of my render in php with donpdf is:

```
"%PDF-1.3 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [6 0 R ] /Count 1 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R /Font << /F1 8 0 R >> >> /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000] >> endobj 4 0 obj [/PDF /Text ] endobj 5 0 obj << /Creator (DOMPDF) /CreationDate (D:20130227215320+00'00') /ModDate (D:20130227215320+00'00') >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 7 0 R >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 66 >> stream x��2�300P@&�ҹ�B�M��́����BH����������BH��B���H�f�B���k�� endstream endobj 8 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F1 /BaseFont /Times-Roman /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj xref 0 9 0000000000 65535 f 0000000008 00000 n 0000000073 00000 n 0000000119 00000 n 0000000273 00000 n 0000000302 00000 n 0000000416 00000 n 0000000479 00000 n 0000000616 00000 n trailer << /Size 9 /Root 1 0 R /Info 5 0 R >> startxref 725 %%EOF"
```

Any idea why `dompdf` renders this response?

This is the code generate Pdf:

```
class PdfView extends PhpView {

public $orientation = "portrait";
public $size = "letter";

function render(Response $response) {
    $response->resetBuffer();
    parent::render($response);
    $buffer = utf8_decode($response->getBuffer());
    $response->resetBuffer();
    Context::load("app/core/lib/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc");
    $pdf = new DOMPDF();
    $pdf->set_paper($this->size,$this->orientation);
    $pdf->load_html($buffer);
    $pdf->render();
    $render = $pdf->output();
    if ($path = @$response->result->options->save)
        file_put_contents($path, $render);
    else {
        $response->setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        echo $render;
    }
}
```

}

The header of app is "application/pdf".
Plz help me!!

Comment: That looks like a PDF. Are you sending the proper content-type header?

Comment: @Pekka웃 is right, that's pretty much a PDF document. Can you post the code you're using? FYI, `$dompdf->stream()` will set the appropriate headers for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The basic issue can be found it in the class library, at the lines:

```
/* FUNCION QUE DARÁ ERRORES*/
/* Function with troubles*/
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $magic_quotes = get_magic_quotes_runtime();
    set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
}
$file_buffer = file_get_contents($path);
$file_buffer = $this->EncodeString($file_buffer, $encoding);
fclose($fd);
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) { set_magic_quotes_runtime($magic_quotes); }
    return $file_buffer;
}
```

You must replace with this code :

```
/* NUEVA FUNCION CORRECTA */
/* Fuction correct*/  
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $magic_quotes = get_magic_quotes_runtime();
    ini_set("magic_quotes_runtime", 0);
}
$file_buffer = file_get_contents($path);
$file_buffer = $this->EncodeString($file_buffer, $encoding);
fclose($fd);
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) { ini_set("magic_quotes_runtime", $magic_quotes); }
    return $file_buffer;
}
```

I hope this code help you :)